# Add tasks to tasks.json for users of a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a vscode extention for a specification language. I would like to provide the users of the plugin with a specific task. The task could be made available using tasks.json. 
Is there a way to add tasks to the tasks.json of a user that uses that extension?

Answer (score 8):

The documentation didn't help me here either. When you provide tasks through the extension there is the [TaskProvider API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider). The example doesn't go into much detail about how these tasks are created though, compared to the classical `tasks.json` approach.

In your package.json you need to define the types of tasks this extension contributes. This has nothing to do with the `type` in `tasks.json`. It's rather a freeform string. If you need custom problem matchers you also need to define theme here.

```
"contributes": {
    "taskDefinitions": [
        {
            "type": "mytask"
        }
    ],
    "problemMatchers": [
        {
            "name": "mywarnings",
            "base": "$gcc",
            "fileLocation": [
                "relative",
                "/"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

In `extension.ts` you need to provide the tasks. Say we have an array of `vscode.Task` in `tasks` you can do:

```
vscode.tasks.registerTaskProvider('mytask', {
    provideTasks: () => {
        return tasks;
    },
    resolveTask(_task: vscode.Task): vscode.Task | undefined {
        // as far as I can see from the documentation this just needs to return undefined.
        return undefined;
    }
});
```

If you want to create a shell task you need the following:

```
new vscode.Task (
    {type: 'shell'}, // this is the same type as in tasks.json
    ws, // The workspace folder
    'name', // how you name the task
    'MyTask', // Shows up as MyTask: name 
    new vscode.ShellExecution(command),
    ["mywarnings"] // list of problem matchers (can use $gcc or other pre-built matchers, or the ones defined in package.json)
);
```

I hope this helps. The bigges issue I see is the overloading of various names (like type), and that the format in tasks.json is completely different to the way tasks are built with TaskProvider API.